# pgfplots y=x graph not rendering all points

Tags: pgfplots

```
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-1em] current bounding box.north)}]
            \begin{axis}
            [
                x = 0.75cm,
                y = 0.75cm,
                xlabel = $x$,
                ylabel = $y$,
                xmin = -10,
                xmax = 10,
                restrict x to domain = -10:10,
                ymin = -10,
                ymax = 10,
                restrict y to domain = -10:10,
                axis x line = middle,
                axis y line = middle,
            ]
                \addplot {x};
                \legend{$y = x$};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: fail]

Why does the graph only render from (-5,-5) to (5,5)? It should be (-10,-10) to (10,10)

Comment: By default `domain=-5:5` I think.

Comment: Wow you were right. What is the purpose of setting the x and y domains separately then?

Comment: `restrict to domain` does not set the domains directly. What they do is to filter out values above or below the given interval. I'll add an answer in a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `restrict <x/y> to domain` keys does not set the domain used for calculating `y` values, that is done by the `domain` key. The default value for `domain`  is `-5:5`, meaning that functions are evaluated for -5 <= x <= 5.

Here is a quote from `pgfplots`' manual about the `restrict` keys:

> These keys append *x* (or *y* or *z*) coordinate filters to restrict the
>   respective coordinate to a domain. The versions without star (like
>   `restrict x to domain`) will assign the value `-inf` if the coordinate is
>   below `min` and `+inf` if the coordinate is above `max` . The starred
>   versions (like `restrict x to domain*`) will truncate coordinates to `[min, max]`, i.e. they assign the value `min` if the coordinate falls
>   outside of the lower limit and `max` if the value falls outside of the
>   upper limit.

The example from the manual has the plot of tan(x) over several cycles.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}    
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
restrict y to domain=-10:10,
samples=1000,
% some fine-tuning for the display:
width=10cm, height=210pt,
xmin=-4.7124, xmax=4.7124,
xtick={-4.7124,-1.5708,...,10},
xticklabels={$-\frac32 \pi$,$-\pi/2$,$\pi/2$,$\frac32 \pi$},
axis x line=center,
axis y line=center]
\addplot[blue] gnuplot[id=tangens,domain=-1.5*pi:1.5*pi]{tan(x)};

\legend{$\tan(x)$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Hence, for your example the `restrict ...` keys are not really needed, and to get the plot for -10 < x 10, add `domain=-10:10`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm,convert={false,density=100}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-1em] current bounding box.north)}]
    \begin{axis}
    [
     x = 0.75cm,
     y = 0.75cm,
     xlabel = $x$,
     ylabel = $y$,
     xmin = -10,
     xmax = 10,
     ymin = -10,
     ymax = 10,
     domain=-10:10,
     axis lines = middle,
    ]
\addplot {x};
\legend{$y = x$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So to get this straight, "domain" is for setting the range of x values to input into the function, "restrict x/y to domain" is for discarding output values from the function that exceed it, and "x/ymin/max" are limits for the drawing of the grid itself?

Comment: @No_name That sounds about right, yes.

Comment: can `domain` automatically equal to `0:ymax` value?

Comment: @alper You can add e.g. `\newcommand\foo{10}` and use  `ymax = \foo, domain=0:\foo`, but I don't know of anything more automated than that.